# Correctness criteria for proof nets

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory, lo.logic, proof-theory, linear-logic

In their paper [*Natural deduction and coherence for weakly distributive categories*](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) Blute, Cockett, Seely and Trimble introduce so-called proof circuits (aka two-sided proof structures) for the positive fragment of multiplicative Linear Logic.
They do not explicitly specify a way of translating proofs in mLL (without negation) into proof circuits, but the translation (say $T$) can be guessed from the names of the respective links (see page 240).
As is usual for proof nets, the authors then give correctness criteria for their proof circuits. That is, they try to answer the question: When does a proof circuit lie in the image of the translation $T$?

Their main correctness criterion is a sequentialization procedure. They try to relate this correctness criterion to the Danos-Regnier criterion, and state on page 250 (Proposition 2.5 on page 22 in the document):

> A (non-planar) $(\oplus,\otimes)$-circuit with components $C$ is sequential if and only if it satisfies the net criterion.

Their proof of the $\Rightarrow$-direction works for planar circuits as well. A counterexample of the $\Leftarrow$-direction for planar circuits is given on page 23 of the document. That leads me to wonder: Is there a graph theoretical correctness criterion a la Danos-Regnier for planar $(\oplus,\otimes)$-circuits? Something like: „A planar $(\oplus,\otimes)$-circuit with components $C$ is sequential if each switching graph is a tree and is … (?).

Comment: In his paper "Natural deduction and coherence in non-symmetric linearly distributive categories" Schneck mentions a criterion (without proof) on page 125: A planar $(\otimes, \oplus)$-circuit is sequential if and only if it satisfies the net criterion and the so-called *region criterion*. If I find the time, I will try to write a more detailed answer.